# When to use gradle.properties vs. settings.gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, build, build-system

A gradle build has three files

- `build.gradle` that defines the build configuration scripts
- `gradle.properties`
- `settings.gradle`

**Questions**

- What are differences between `settings.gradle` & `gradle.properties`?
- When should a settings be put in `settings.gradle` vs.
  `gradle.properties`?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

#### `settings.gradle`

The `settings.gradle` file is a Groovy script, just like the `build.gradle` file. Only one `settings.gradle` script will be executed in each build (in comparison to multiple `build.gradle` scripts in multi-project builds). The `settings.gradle` script will be executed before any `build.gradle` script and even before the [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) instances are created. Therefore, it is evaluated against a [`Settings`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html) object. With this `Settings` object you can add subprojects to your build, modify the parameters from the command line ([`StartParameter`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html)), and access the [`Gradle`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html) object to register lifecycle handlers. As a consequence, use `settings.gradle` if your settings are build-related and not necessarily project-related or require logic **before** possible subprojects are included.

#### `gradle.properties`

The `gradle.properties` file is a simple Java [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) file that only gains a special role by being automatically included into the scope of the `Project` object (as so-called 'project properties'). It's a simple key-value store that only allows string values (so you need to split lists or arrays by yourself). You can put `gradle.properties` files to these locations:

- directly in the project directory (for project-related values)
- in the user home `.gradle` directory (for user- or environment-related values)

Answer (score 108):

A multi-module project has **one main module** and many submodules. It has this layout:

```
(root)
  +- settings.gradle       
  +- build.gradle          # optional (commonly present)
  +- gradle.properties     # optional
  +-- buildSrc/            # optional
  |     +- build.gradle    
  |     +-- src/...
  +-- build-conventions/   # optional
  |     +- settings.gradle # empty
  |     +- build.gradle
  |     +-- src/
  |           +-- myconvention.gradle
  +-- my-gradle-stuff/     # optional
  |     +- utils.gradle    # optional
  +-- sub-a/
  |     +- build.gradle
  |     +- src/
  +-- sub-b/
        +- build.gradle
        +- src/
```

submodules can also be located deeper in subfolders, but without modifying code in settings.gradle, their name will include the name of such folders.

### settings.gradle

The main role of settings.gradle is to define all included submodules and to mark the directory root of a tree of modules, so you can only have one `settings.gradle` file in a multi-module project.

```
rootProject.name = 'project-x'

include 'sub-a', 'sub-b'
```

The settings file is also written in groovy, and submodule lookup can be customized.

### build.gradle

There is one such file per module, it contains the build logic for this module.

In the `build.gradle` file of the **main module**, you can use `allprojects {}` or `subprojects {}` to define settings for all other modules.

In the `build.gradle` file of the submodules, you can use `compile project(':sub-a')` to make one submodule depend on the other.

### gradle.properties

This is optional, its main purpose is to provide startup options to use for running gradle itself, e.g.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx=... -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ...
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

These values can be overridden by a file `USER_HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties`, and overriden by gradle command line arguments. Also it is possible to set environment variables for the build in this file using `systemProp.` as prefix.

Any property in this file can be used in any build.gradle, so some projects also put dependency version or release information in `gradle.properties`, but that is likely an abuse of this file.

### my-gradle-stuff/utils.gradle

(Any name of folder or file is possible.)
You can define additional custom gradle files to reuse definitions, and include them in other gradle files via

```
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/utils.gradle"
```

other places to put this might be `src/gradle` or `src/build/gradle`

### buildSrc/...

This folder is special, it is like a separate gradle project in itself. It is built before doing anything else, and can provide function to use in any other gradle file. **Because of technical reasons, IDE support for references to this folder work much better than any other way of extracting common code from multiple `build.gradle` files to a separate location.**

You can define complex custom build logic in java, groovy or kotlin, instead of writing and deploying a plugin. This is also useful for unit-testing your custom build code, as you can have unit tests. The source folder structure in `buildSrc` can be adapted like for any java/groovy/kotlin project.

### build-conventions/...

This element is optional and used as a replacement for buildSrc when the logic to be shared is simple, like version numbers, and should not necessarily trigger a full rebuild of a large project for just changing one version of one dependency. The name of this directory is arbitrary, it needs however to be included in the root settings.gradle like this: `includeBuild 'build-conventions'`, and it's build.gradle should have `plugins {id("groovy-gradle-plugin")}`.

this then allows to extract build logic in `.gradle files` that can simply be included in other modules like this `plugins {id("myconvention")}`.

This can also be combined with the `buildSrc` folder.